# Change Polygon color

Tags: c#, wpf

I am adding `MouseEnter` event handler from C# code as follows:

```
var polygon = new Polygon { StrokeThickness = 1, Fill = Brushes.Blue };
polygon.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(p_MouseLeftButtonDown2);

...

void p_MouseLeftButtonDown2(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Entered");
}
```

How can I change the color of the polygon in `p_MouseLeftButtonDown2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put this into the `p_MouseLeftButtonDown2` method:

```
((Polygon)sender).Fill = Brushes.Black; //whatever color you need
```

If I were you, however, I would look into the possibility of replacing this whole code-behind with a MVVM approach.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to solve this task.
I think U R really new in WPF and maybe in C# too, so I suppose following solution for you:

```
void p_MouseLeftButtonDown2(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Polygon poly = sender as Polygon;
    if (poly != null)
        poly.Fill = Brushes.Red;
}
```

Fancy way is `Storyboard`